# Is it possible to have more than 10 test numbers for Firebase Phone Authentication?

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-authentication

My project has a base app in flutter plus several white labels and they are all linked to only one Firebase project.

Now I got to a point where I need more than 10 test numbers for the Firebase Phone Auth. Does anyone know if its possible, if not, how could I sort this problem?

Any help will be very much appreciated

Answer (score 1):

Firebase projects are not meant for white label applications. From the documentation on [understanding projects](https://firebase.google.com/docs/projects/learn-more):

> ... if you develop a white label application, each independently labelled app should have its own Firebase project, but the iOS and Android versions of that label can be in the same project

There is no way to increase the number of test devices on your own. While you can [reach out to Firebase support](https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/troubleshooting/) to see if they have any means, I doubt they will, given how your use case compares to the stated way of handling white labeled apps.